# Why does this While loop cycle twice?

Tags: java, while-loop, iteration

I made this while loop that is supposed to fulfill functions for different shapes and after it fulfills the function for that shape, it will keep asking for shapes until the user types "Exit". I have only done Triangles so far so I just have some filler functions to fulfill to make sure that it loops correctly. The problem is, after I'm done with triangles, it will print the menu twice before asking for an input instead of just printing once. Can anyone explain this to me?

```
while(password){
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("---Welcome to the Shape Machine---");
    System.out.println("Available Options:");
    System.out.println("Circles");
    System.out.println("Rectangles");
    System.out.println("Triangles");
    System.out.println("Exit");
    String option = keyboard.nextLine();

    if(option.equals("Exit")){
        System.out.println("Terminating the program. Have a nice day!");
        return; 
    } else if(option.equals("Triangles")){
        System.out.println("Triangles selected. Please enter the 3 sides:");
        int sideA = 0;
        int sideB = 0;
        int sideC = 0;
        do{
            sideA = keyboard.nextInt();
            sideB = keyboard.nextInt();
            sideC = keyboard.nextInt();

            if(sideA<0 || sideB<0 || sideC<0)
                System.out.println("#ERROR Negative input. Please input the 3 sides again.");
        } while(sideA<0 || sideB<0 || sideC<0);

        if((sideA+sideB)<=sideC || (sideB+sideC)<=sideA || (sideA+sideC)<=sideB){
            System.out.println("#ERROR Triangle is not valid. Returning to menu.");
            continue;
        } else {
            System.out.println("good job!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `password` and why is it never reset inside of your loop?

Answer (score 0):

It might be that you are using `keyboard.nextLine();`. In your code outside the while loop make sure that you are always using `.nextLine()` and nothing else.

Reasoning: If you use `.next()`, it'll only consume one word so the next time you call `.nextLine()`, it'll consume the end of that line.

Answer (score 0):

After you say `sideC = keyboard.nextInt()` the carriage return that you typed (after typing the number) is still in the input buffer. Then you print the menu and execute `String option = keyboard.nextLine();` That command reads up to and including the first newline it finds, which is the newline that is still in the buffer.
So `option` is now a bare newline character, which does not match "Exit" or "Triangle", so it loops again and prints th menu again.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is caused by left-over characters like space, carriage-return, newline, form-feed in the input buffer.

Since the next *keyboard.nextLine()* doesn't match any of given options (and since there is no "else" at the bottom of while loop to deal with this case), the control goes into next iteration, prints the options again. Based on surrounding context of processing of input, there are several good answers to address this problem on SO.

Since your intention is to skip over all blanks, carriage-returns, newlines, form-feeds till you get a valid string (*option*) again, the following code works best in a case like yours.

```
System.out.println();
System.out.println("---Welcome to the Shape Machine---");
//...
System.out.println("Exit");
String option = keyboard.nextLine();
keyboard.skip("[\\s]*");
```